# How can I use Font Awesome vectors in Illustrator?

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-illustrator

I'm stumped. As directed, I printed the [Font Awesome Cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) to PDF. When I open it with Acrobat Reader, it looks fine. However, when I try to open it with Illustrator, I get this warning:

> The font MuseoSlab-500 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
> The font OTS-derived-font is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
> The font ProximaNova-Regular is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.

How can I 'fix' the PDF, so that I can see and use the icons in Illustrator?

Comment: Try zamzar https://www.zamzar.com/

Answer (score 0):

Open the PDF in Acrobat Pro, Save as... to Encapculated Postscript (.eps)

It will create two separate files that can be opened in Adobe Illustrator. The icons and type should all be converted to outlines.

Comment: Can I convert the PDF to EPS with any other tool, or must I do it with Acrobat Pro? I appreciate the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Time has moved on the current [cheat sheet pages](https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/free/solid) (V5 not current V6?) have a print button and the output works perfectly in Adobe products such as reader DC.

There are guides for "cut and paste" use in desktop applications such as graphics apps, but the key point is the font must have been installed.
https://fontawesome.com/docs/desktop/add-icons/glyphs

> On the Desktop
> After you have Font Awesome set up on the desktop , you can copy any icon's name here and paste it into a text field and let ligatures do the rest of the work (when supported by your desktop app). Or you can also copy and paste the icon (not the unicode) directly from this page into a text layer as a glyph .

[image]